# Dragging finger randomly

Tags: android, android-studio

In my app I try to achieve this:

When I randomly drag my finger through the screen, the **button** under it makes some action.
Do i need to make custom views? If yes, what view?
So far I used `onTouchListener`, correct me if i am wrong.
Any help will be appreciated.

[image: click]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should use custom view only if you need to display something for user. Otherwise properly handling action up/down/move logic with wrapper class around `onTouchListener` of whole layout would be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can for example place single view over your *Buttons*, and use onTouchListener to determine above which button is the finger dragged. And highlight (do required action) the required button.

This way you'll have to manually calculate above which Button is the finger dragging.

Comment: So do i need to make somethig like this:
button.setOnTouchListener(new..)
public void onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
if [finger is in some particular x and y]{
do something}
Correct me if I am thinking wrong
Thanks for answer, @Vlad Matvienko

Comment: @OldYork, not actually a Button. You should place a Frame Layout above all the buttons for example, and set ontouch to it.

Comment: Okay, but is it possible to set making action only when finger is in set dimensions (x,y)?

Comment: If by isViewInBounds(), what should I write in ()?